Barcode Scanner using KeyEvent not getting Characters after clicking on Entry from another view
The application I am trying is using Honeywell CT45P device and its functionality seems a bit odd. I have an application that picks up if the barcode has been scanned with this DispatchKeyEvent.
    public override bool DispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e)
    {

        if (e.Characters != null)
        {
            var value = e.Characters;

            WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new BarcodeScannedMessage(value));
        }

        return base.DispatchKeyEvent(e);
    }

When it picks up the barcode, the KeyEvent would have KeyCode.Unknown and KeyAction.Action_multiple. (as mentioned in the Android notes (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent#ACTION_MULTIPLE).
However the issue starts from here. When user opens up the app, they need to click a button to navigate to another view and pick an option from picker in order for the scanned barcode to be properly saved. When I click back to go back to the main view to scan barcodes after the picker, it won't ever have Keycode.Unknown and KeyAction.Action_Multiple (rather it gets KeyAction.Action_Down and KeyAction.Action_UP) KeyAction.Characters will always be null.
Only way to fix this is for user to either drag down the status bar (the drawer for android where you can select wi-fi, data, brightness, etc) or I have to click the overview button and go back into the app afterwards.
One more thing I have already tried was to create a test entry on the main view and set it to focus onAppearing() then scanning.
It populates the entry with the barcode content but the KeyEvent is not getting hit.
Update: It seems like focusing on the Entry will populate text but it won't ever throw KeyEventAction.Multiple causing the above code to never hit. But when I complete the Entry by hitting return when Entry is focused, it will start throwing KeyEventAction.Multiple again and Program is able to pickup the barcode once more. It seem like Focus is not the issue but whether if certain entities are completed?
